# How to change the view angle from persp3d plot in R

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I have the following function to generate a rainbow sphere,

```
library(rgl)
f = function(s, t){
    cbind(cos(s) * cos(t),
    sin(s) * cos(t), 
    sin(t))
}

persp3d(f, slim = c(0, pi), tlim = c(0, 2*pi), col = rainbow,theta = 20,phi=60)
```

however, the 'theta' and 'phi' seems not to work in this command, no matter what value I choose I still get one particular view like this.

[image]

can anybody tell me how to solve this problem? I want this plot to have different views as I change value of 'theta' and 'phi'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theta` and `phi` aren't arguments to `persp3d()`, but you can call a separate function `view3d()` to set them.  If you don't want to see the first display followed by the move, use `par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)` before drawing and restore the old value afterwards.  Your example would be

```
library(rgl)
f = function(s, t){
    cbind(cos(s) * cos(t),
    sin(s) * cos(t), 
    sin(t))
}

save <- par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)
persp3d(f, slim = c(0, pi), tlim = c(0, 2*pi), col = rainbow)
view3d(theta = 20, phi = 60)
par3d(save)
```